# For a spring application, do changes made to application context propagation levels take immediate effect?

Tags: web-applications, spring-transactions, applicationcontext, propagation

I have a web application in production that is based on spring transactions. propagation levels are set in applicationcontext.xml. Will tomcat pick up any change I make to the propagation levels in this xml with a restart? of do I have to redeploy the entire war?

Comment: Restart should do it. A new Spring Context would be created from the XML configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, applicationContext.xml will be IN your WAR file. In this case you will need to redeploy it.
If for some reason it is outside your WAR, then changing it and restarting tomcat will be OK.
PS of course you can change the applicationContext.xml in the exploded version of your WAR but this is not suggested as changes will be overridden on the next deployment.

Comment: So, for testing purpose if I change the applicationContext.xml in the already exploded WAR, the new propagation levels will take effect without a tomcat restart. Is that understanding correct?

Comment: No, restarting will always be required as a new application context must be built, which happens at startup time.

Comment: ok, if it is restarted will the changes I made in the app context of the exploded war get wiped away as there will be a redeploy when tomcat gets restarted?

Comment: No, because generally a restart of Tomcat will NOT trigger a redeploy, unless you have a special setup.